# Updated to 8.5.1, but front end says 8.5.0 is installed

Tags: updating, composer

I did the update from 8.4.5 to 8.5.x with Composer. I had some issues, but finally got it to work. Now, if I do

```
drush status
```

It says

```
Drupal version   : 8.5.1
```

If I look at the version listed in core/lib/Drupal.php it says

```
const VERSION = '8.5.1';
```

But in admin/reports/updates/update it says

```
INSTALLED VERSION 8.5.0
```

I've cleared caches and tried running update.php just for giggles. Can't figure out why Drupal is confused.

Any ideas?

Comment: What were those issues? They might be related.

Comment: I'm inclined to think not — it was refusing to update the site because symfony was out of date. Took me a little while to figure out that I needed to tell composer to update the dependencies too.